# Unknow ltp dio30 test error. The SSD disk is dead

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, hard-disk

Environment:

- LTP version: ltp-full-20230127
- CPU: FT-2000+(arm64)
- Run LTP command:

  ```
  nohup ./runltp -p -l /home/result.log -d /home -t 168h &
  ```

Bug description:

When I run `ltp alltest`, after several loops' alltest, the machine will become unresponsive, with desktop and other programs or daemons dead, but the Linux kernel  alive, the serial port prints some driver logs when I connect or disconnecgt USB mouse/keyboard from USB port.

The "Zombie" status due to dio30, which fork 100 child tasks, and call `writev`/`readv` from diff offset of the file parallel. Below is exception log from debug serial.

```bash
[120193.657816][ T4867] LTP: starting dio29 (diotest3 -b 65536 -n 100 -i 100 -o 1024000)
[120235.231643][ T4867] LTP: starting dio30 (diotest6 -b 65536 -n 100 -i 100 -o 1024000)
[120309.495026][  T520] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[120309.502838][  T520] ata1.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[120309.508568][  T520] ata1.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 3
[120309.508568][  T520]          res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[120309.523626][  T520] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[120309.528059][  T520] ata1: hard resetting link
[120309.845188][  T520] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[120315.083035][  T520] ata1.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
[120315.088968][  T520] ata1.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
[120315.095816][  T520] ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
[120315.101456][  T520] ata1: hard resetting link
[120315.421212][  T520] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[120325.579067][  T520] ata1.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
[120325.584993][  T520] ata1.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
[120325.591839][  T520] ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
[120325.597477][  T520] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[120325.603375][  T520] ata1: hard resetting link
[120325.921250][  T520] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 320)
[120356.555202][  T520] ata1.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
[120356.561140][  T520] ata1.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
[120356.567989][  T520] ata1.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
[120356.573627][  T520] ata1.00: disabled
[120356.893376][  T520] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 320)
[120356.901385][  T520] ata1: EH complete
[120356.905154][    C1] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=107s
[120356.915726][    C1] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[120356.924904][    C1] print_req_error: 8 callbacks suppressed
[120356.924908][    C1] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[120356.941398][   C18] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[120356.951796][   C18] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[120356.960982][   C18] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[120356.971813][   C18] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[120356.982635][   C18] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[120356.993457][   C18] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[120357.004277][   C18] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[120357.015098][   C18] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[120357.025919][   C18] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[120357.036738][   C18] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[120357.047559][   C18] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[120357.058502][    C2] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#21 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[120357.058519][   C35] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
Mar 23 03:11:46 [120357.058590][   C32] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
ltptest kernel: [120357.058596][   C32] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1b d7 9f 00 00 00 08 00
ata1.00: excepti[120357.058614][   C32] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
on Emask 0x0 SAc[120357.058616][   C32] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#27 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1b a7 a8 b0 00 00 08 00
t 0x0 SErr 0x0 a[120357.058636][T813309] dm-0: writeback error on inode 201930164, offset 32047104, sector 113798912
ction 0x6 frozen[120357.058640][T813309] dm-0: writeback error on inode 201930629, offset 913408, sector 110655664
```

The test dir is special, which mount dir combined with a SSD partation and a HDD disk partation.

```
[root@ltptest home]# lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1         8:1    0 238.5G  0 part 
  ├─uos-root 253:0    0    70G  0 lvm  /
  └─uos-home 253:2    0   3.8T  0 lvm  /home
sdb            8:16   0   3.6T  0 disk 
├─sdb1         8:17   0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2         8:18   0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sdb3         8:19   0   3.6T  0 part 
  ├─uos-swap 253:1    0     4G  0 lvm  
  └─uos-home 253:2    0   3.8T  0 lvm  /home
```

From debug serial log ,I only get the SSD may be dead when diotest6 flush data to storage.But I do not reason what bug cause this error, Anyone have some ideas about this bug?